# How to read a file downloaded by selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am using selenium with webdriver in python to download a csv file from a site . The file gets downloaded into the download directory specified. Here is an overview of my code

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",'xx/yy')
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get('url')
```

I need to `print` the contents of this csv to the terminal . A lot of similar files with random names will be downloaded into the same folder so accessing the file via filename wont work as I don't know what it will be in advance

Comment: You can't open and read csv file with selenium, you need to use file readers libraries.

Comment: Can you post the html? maybe you can extract the file name from there

Comment: The filename isn't present anywhere in the html . Sorry but its sensitive information so I can't post it . I've checked it thoroughly though. I had a feeling that i might have to read the file using a file library , but I would still need the file name right . Is there a way to view the filename in the driver.get() or is there a way to print the file contents from the response to the screen?

Comment: [Autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) provides windows interface, including file explorer. Maybe you can use it to get the file by date (last downloaded for example), but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I have to run this on an ubuntu server , and there are going to be several(1000 +) instances of this code running at once so getting the file by date isn't reliable

Comment: I had a similar test case in which the number of files to be downloaded was not deterministic. The test needed to ensure, that any of these files contained a specific string. So the solution was to read one file after another (using a globbed name pattern like "robot*.txt") grepping for the serach string. That test was written in java. But I am sure you can do something like that in python, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was formed from a combination of previous stack overflow questions , answers as well as comments in this post so thank you everyone.

I combined selenium webdriver and the python requests module for this solution . I essentially logged into the site using selenium, copied the cookies from the webdriver session and then used a requests.get(url,cookies = webdriver_cookies) to get the file.

Here's the gist of my solution

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False) 
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",'xx/yy') 
fp.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', "text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/csv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream") 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)

# selenium login code ...

driver_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
cookies_copy = {}
for driver_cookie in driver_cookies:
    cookies_copy[driver_cookie["name"]] = driver_cookie["value"]
r = requests.get('url',cookies = cookies_copy)
print r.text
```

I hope that this helps someone

Answer (score 5):

You can get the last downloaded file from that location and then read the file:

```
path = /path to folder
list = os.listdir(path)
time_sorted_list = sorted(list, key=os.path.getmtime)
file_name = time_sorted_list[len(time_sorted_list)-1]
```

and then u can read from this file. Hoping not multiple files are getting there by parallel processes.

EDIT:
Just saw comment that multiple instances are up for downloading, so other way around you can use urllib and download the file by using its url as:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve( "http://www.example.com/yourfile.ext", "your-file-name.ext") // you can provide unique-id to your file name
```

Comment: That wont work as the site that I'm downloading the file from requires a sign in and hence session data which is done by selenium . The session data is associated with the webdriver object . So a simple urlretrieve() gives me a IOError: ('http error', 401, 'Unauthorized')

Answer (score 1):

Downloading files in Selenium is never a good idea. You cannot control where and under which filename the file is downloaded, and if you want to find out, then you have to use dirty hacks. It depends on the browser and its settings and if the same file has already been downloaded before or not.

Plus, you have to take care of deleting the file after the download, bc otherwise, numerous copies of the same file will spam your hard drive until it's completely full.

If possible, you should call something like

```
string downloadUrl = ButtonDownloadPdf.GetAttribute("href");
```

and then handle the downloading yourself, using conventional methods, not Selenium.

Comment: its not my first choice . Its a last resort

Comment: @Kimmy Would you bother to explain why it is not a good idea or do you rather risk down-votes? If a test case mandates that files are to be downloaded and checked, then why not automate it using Selenium?

Comment: @Kimmy Thanks for elaborating. I still disagree for three reasons 1) You _can_ control where the file is downloaded (browser setting) and the files have at least a default name; 2) You should not delete the files _after_ downloading in order to be able to check the file, if the test failed. You should delete old files _before_ running an automated test to clean up. Any problem with that? 3) Even if your claim no less than testing **everything with every possible browser automatically**, others might be content with running some exotic tests with one browser only - rather than manual or no test

Comment: A use case for downloading files in Selenium is scraping sites that do not expose links in an obvious way