# Selenium: Opening a Downloaded File in Java

Tags: java, file, selenium, download

I need to open and read a downloaded file using selenium and I'm not quite sure how to do it. I see answers that suggests to download the file in a selected location. Does my code really need to start from downloading the file to selected location or can it start directly after downloading?

After opening the file I must also read it. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: possible dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899836/how-to-read-a-file-downloaded-by-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Answer (score -1):

You can read file using following code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileExample1 {

    private static final String FILENAME = "E:\\test\\filename.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {

            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this line of code to handel download a file from chrome and forefox browser.

```
public static File waitForDownloadToComplete(File downloadPath, String fileName) throws Exception {
        boolean isFileFound = false;
        int waitCounter = 0;
        while (!isFileFound) {
            logger.info("Waiting For Download To Complete....");
            for (File tempFile : downloadPath.listFiles()) {
                if (tempFile.getName().contains(fileName)) {
                    String tempEx = FilenameUtils.getExtension(tempFile.getName());
                    // crdownload - For Chrome, part - For Firefox
                    if (tempEx.equalsIgnoreCase("crdownload") || tempEx.equalsIgnoreCase("part")) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } else {
                        isFileFound = true;
                        logger.info("Download To Completed....");
                        return tempFile;
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            waitCounter++;
            if (waitCounter > 25) {
                isFileFound = true;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("File Not Downloaded");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you!