# Upload file using Selenium with Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to upload files to a website using selenium with the chromedriver. Everything works fine
when I manually enter the file path: `file_input.send_keys('C:\Scans\Test.pdf')`

### The problem

The exception gets thrown when I introduce a for-loop iterate a list of file paths.

```
for path in pathlist:
    if path.endswith('pdf'):
        file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='attacheFile']")
        file_input.send_keys(path)
```

The error comes with the `send_keys` portion of the code.

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: File not found : 
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.117)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

### What I've tried

**Decoding the path**

```
for path in pathlist:
    if path.endswith('pdf'):
        modifpath = os.fsdecode(path)
        file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='attacheFile']")
        file_input.send_keys(modifpath)
```

**Replacing the / with //**

```
for path in pathlist:
    if path.endswith('pdf'):
        modifpath = os.fsdecode(path)
        modifpath = modifpath.replace("\\", '\\\\')
        file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='attacheFile']")
        file_input.send_keys(modifpath)
```

**Using the os.path.abspath tool on the decoded path**

```
for path in pathlist:
    if path.endswith('pdf'):
        modifpath = os.fsdecode(path)
        file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='attacheFile']")
        file_input.send_keys(os.path.abspath(modifpath))
```

**Using the os.path.abspath tool on the original path**

```
for path in pathlist:
    if path.endswith('pdf'):
        file_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='attacheFile']")
        file_input.send_keys(os.path.abspath(path))
```

Do you have any suggestions? I've looked everywhere but couldn't find an answer except to use the AutoIt module which is not a cross-platform alternative.

Comment: Try this:  
drv.find_element_by_id("IdOfInputTypeFile").send_keys(os.getcwd()+"/image.png")

Comment: I can't use os.getcwd() as my files are stored on a different disk and the filename change a lot so simply adding the /image.png wouldn't solve my problem. I already have the full file path stored in a list but selenium seems to be unable to accept it when it's fed in as a variable... Thanks for your input by the way.

Comment: What do you get when you print `path` before sending it? Are you aware of escaping a raw string with `r"sometext"`?

Comment: No, there is no raw string. (r') It's a normal string. Have you guys ever uploaded a path without writing it explicitly? (ex: C:\Scan\Image.pdf)

Comment: Print the path before you use it... what is the exact string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a file downloaded by selenium webdriver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899836/how-to-read-a-file-downloaded-by-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: It depends. Every solution I've tried produced a different path. For example, the original path when printed is: C:\Scan\Image.pdf
The path when printed for every solution I've tried is:
1-C:\Scan\Image.pdf
2-C:\\Scan\\Image.pdf
3-C:\Scan\Image.pdf
4-C:\Scan\Image.pdf

Comment: @BlkPengu: I don't think it's a duplicate since the post you mentioned is about downloading and saving the files gathered via Selenium. My post is about uploading files to a website using Selenium.