# Python read downloaded file as a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have come up with below script to download a file using selenium but now I am looking for a solution to read the downloaded file into a pandas dataframe.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

DRIVER_PATH = r"C:\Users\u123456\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
d = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
d.get('https://chartink.com/screener/copy-supertrend-negative-breakout-1103')
element = d.find_element_by_link_text("Download csv")
d1 = element.click()
```

The only option I can think of is to scan the downloaded location and pick the latest file but I am interested to know if there is any other better solution.
TIA
mc

Comment: It seems like your options are either to grab the latest file from your downloads folder, or somehow get the file URL from the site (which might not work on the provided site) and download the file with `requests`. See the answers to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899836/how-to-read-a-file-downloaded-by-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: ya but as you said the issue is with the URL, how to get the URL?

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do it is to scrape the name of the file you downloaded and search for that, after you have waited until its downloaded, and then load it into pandas the normal way

Comment: The issue with this approach is, if we I download the file multiple times the file name gets appended with 1, 2 etc locally.

Comment: @mrcool4 You can change the file once its read to keep it consistent and to keep a logical order of things, IE once you have read the file and used its content either delete it or rename it to ```filename-dd-mm-yy```

Comment: What if the script runs parallelly and picks the same file twice? I do not want to skip any file.

Comment: Then it might be a viable option to let your program run and download everything (keeping track of how many files you've downloaded) and get all the data at once. Or as ive noticed once you click the link a href tag appears on the button ```blob:https://chartink.com/<Hash>```, it might also be an option to use this as this link will download a unique file name that you can actually use and can scrape properly as well. It's not the nicest but it will allow you to keep tack of everything

Comment: Thanks @Norton409. But it looks like the href link keeps changing everyday. Do I have to find the pattern and extract the link in each run?

Comment: No worries! The link changes every time you click it unfortunately, not the most ideal. Due to the nature of downloading files in parallel and the inability to name downloaded files on download, this would be a good way to track each of them and make sure there is no overwrites or mixing up of files.